# If a parent menu item is clicked, automatically expand a specific submenu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

My e-commerce store requires three tier menu item to achieve the multi-column megamenu appearance that I want, and although its a bit weird I have found a workaround on desktop by simply hiding the "middle" menu item as "shown" here by the red box (as in there are menu items there, but they are display none).

[image]

This is honestly fine, as I hover over the parent menu item, and then only see the li menu items. However my issue is actually on mobile, where the expanding of the top menu item requires a click, and then I need to click a second time to expand the "middle" menu item as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

There is an event attached to both "caret" clicks, and that is:

```
function(e) {
  e.target.closest("li").classList.toggle("dropdown-open"), e.preventDefault()
}
```

This attaches an event to the menu item as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

..and that allows the submenu to appear below "Weighing Categories" like this:

[image]

So my goal (on the mobile viewport) is to show all the submenu items (with the exception of the middle one, in this case "weighing categories") when the categories caret is clicked. I have tried a CSS approach (which is what the dropdown-open class is basically adding), but this results in it always showing (whereas I still want to keep the first click, just not the second click requirement).

```
body .main-navigation ul.menu li.menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu-wrapper {  position: inherit; left: auto; opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0); }
```

I have also tried multiple variations of using JS to insert a class, and I think this is on the right track, but missing something lol.. I must admit that my JS is poor, mainly trying examples I have found during my research and adapting them.

```
jQuery("nav-menu-item-1247 .caret").click(function() {
jQuery("#nav-menu-item-6721").addClass( "dropdown-open");

});
```

The above (and note that it is not working) was supposed to add "dropdown-open" proactively to the weighing categories menu item ("6721") when the top menu item (the "1247" is the "categories" one) is clicked. Perhaps the prevent default in the default JS is blocking it, I am not sure and do not have the skill to troubleshoot it lol.

I would really appreciate some help, been fighting with this for almost 4 hours and I am probably doing something stupid lol. I can share the URL if needed, it is just locked behind a user/pass before it goes live, but I can temporarily remove it.

Thanks :)

Comment: Nearly impossible to debug menu code just from images with no code. Please provide a [mre]